# How can I run some code on all objects retrieved from ActiveRecord?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I want to initialize some attributes in retrieved objects with values received from an external API. `after_find` and `after_initialize` callbacks won't work for me as this way I have to call the API for each received object, which is is quite slow. I want something like the following:

```
class Server < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessor :dns_names
  ...
  after_find_collection do |servers|
    all_dns_names = ForeignLibrary.get_all_dns_entries
    servers.each do |s|
      s.dns_names = all_dns_names.select{|r| r.ip == s.ip}.map{|r| r.fqdn}
    end
  end
end
```

Please note that caching is not a solution, as I need to always have current data, and the data may be changed outside the application.

Comment: How are you planning on keeping your data up-to-date without querying to API each time?

Comment: @JamesBrewer I want it to be current on every page load, but for that page load I want it to take just one API request.

Comment: And you would have multiple items on that page that you need to use the data for? I might be misunderstanding something because short-term caching sounds like a perfect solution. Save the data to a file (or hold it in memory -- depending on the size) and querying it for each item should work.

Comment: Yep. I have a table on a page with each row corresponding to server and column with server's domain names. Expected behaviour is to change data externally, reload page and see the results. It's internal project, so high load is not a concern.

Comment: I stand caching. Just use an expiration appropriate for how often you want to update your data.

Comment: @JamesBrewer ok, may be for this particular task caching really fits well. But anyway, imagine it's not an API request, but some computation, dependent on all returned results. I'm just curious how this can be achieved in Rails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd want to have a class method that enhances each server found with your data. so, something like:

```
def index
  servers = Server.where(condition: params[:condition]).where(second: params[:second])
  @servers = Server.with_domains_names(servers)
end

class Server
  def self.with_domain_names(servers)
    all_dns_names = ForeignLibrary.get_all_dns_entries
    servers.each do |s|
      s.dns_names = all_dns_names.select{|r| r.ip == s.ip}.map{|r| r.fqdn}
    end
  end
end
```

This way, the `ForeignLibrary.get_all_dns_entries` only gets run once, and you can enhance your servers with that extra information.

If you wanted to do this every time you initialize a server object, I'd simply delegate rather than use `after_initialize`. So you'd effectively store the all dns entries in a global variable, and then cache it for a period of time. ForeignLibrary.get_all_dns_entries call. So, it would be something like:

```
class Server
  def dns_names
    ForeignLibrary.dns_for_server(self)
  end
end

class ForeignLibrary

  def self.reset
    @@all_dns_names = nil
  end

  def self.dns_for_server(server)
    all_dns_names.select{|r| r.ip == server.ip}.map{|r| r.fqdn}
  end

  def self.all_dns_names
    Mutex.new.synchronize do
      @@all_dns_names ||= call_the_library_expensively
    end
  end
end
```

(I also used a mutex here since we are doing ||= with class variables)

to use it, you would:

```
class ApplicationController
  before_filter do
    ForeignLibrary.reset #ensure every page load has the absolute latest data
  end
end
```